# Time difference issue when adding a Google Calendar Event using C#

Tags: c#, timezone, google-calendar-api, gdata-api

I am using "Google.GData.Calendar" API to add Events to the Google Calendar using c#. But there is time difference between the events created in my DB and Google Calendar.

Following is the Code to add an Event to Google Calendar using the Google.GData API:

```cs
public static void AddEventToGoogle()
{
    //string timezone = "US Mountain Standard Time";

    Uri postUri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full");
    try
    {
        GOAuthRequestFactory authFactory = new GOAuthRequestFactory("cl", "MyApp");
        authFactory.ConsumerKey =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GConsumerKey"].ToString();
        authFactory.ConsumerSecret =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GConsumerKeySecret"].ToString();
        authFactory.Token = "xxxxxxxxxx";
        authFactory.TokenSecret = "xxxxxx";
        Google.GData.Calendar.CalendarService service = new Google.GData.Calendar.CalendarService(authFactory.ApplicationName);
        service.RequestFactory = authFactory;

        EventEntry entry = new EventEntry();
        entry.Title.Text = "Test Google Event Create";
        entry.Content.Content = "Test Google Event Create";
        entry.Notifications = false;

        When eventTime = new When();
        eventTime.AllDay = false;
        eventTime.StartTime = new DateTime(2013, 5, 9, 8, 0, 0);
        eventTime.EndTime = new DateTime(2013, 5, 9, 11, 0, 0);
        entry.Times.Add(eventTime);

        // Send the request and receive the response:
        EventEntry insertedEntry = service.Insert(postUri, entry);
        if (insertedEntry != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(insertedEntry.EventId))
        {
            //Get the insertedEntry.EventId
        }
    }
    catch (GDataRequestException gre)
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)gre.Response;
    }
}
```

But with the above code there is a time difference with the event I intended to create and the entry in the Google Calendar. The TimeZone I have in my Google Calendar is "(GMT-07:00) Mountain Time - Arizona". This is happening when i change the TimeZones of my Google Calendar to CST, PST,...

Please suggest a workaround for this situation or where do I need to specify the TimeZone while adding an event to Google Calendar.

**Updated my question with the complete method i used to add an event**

Comment: Can you post your data as it is posted to the API?  I don't think that it's the language you're using causing the problem.  Instead the format of the date.  From the docs:  "The time, as a combined date-time value (formatted according to RFC 3339). A time zone offset is required unless a time zone is explicitly specified in 'timeZone'."

Comment: bvstone, please check my updated question with the sample

Answer (score 0):

The GData library uses v2 of the Google APIs.  I think you will need to migrate your code to v3 in order to get proper support for time zones on events.

For example, see [this page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/recurringevents) which shows an example of creating a recurring event.  (Switch to the ".NET" tab".

Here are some resources that may help you:

- [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/migration)
- [What's new in v3](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/whats-new)  (it doesn't mention time zones though)
- [Client libraries](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/setup)  (see the ".NET" tab)

I did look through your code and the reference guide to the v2 GData library.  I only see TimeZone properties on the `CalendarEntry`, `EventFeed`, and `EventQuery` classes. Since you're not using any of those, I don't think it is possible in v2.

**UPDATE**

It is *possible* in the v2 API.  You can pass a time zone in the ICAL formatted `<gd:recurrence>` tag.  Take a look at the note following the example in [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_protocol#CreatingRecurring).

However, it doesn't appear that it is exposed as a property of the `EventEntry` class in the .Net GData client library.  So my recommendation stands - use the v3 api and client library.

Comment: Matt, Thanks for the update. I'll check on available samples to convert the V2 to V3.